# Google Cloud SQL - Increase storage for server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

How can I increase the storage on my server through the Developer's Console

[image]

I have went over the amount of storage alotted and need to increase. I have tried attaching a larger disk but this did not work. How do I do this?

Comment: Per https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#maxstorage, "If you require more storage, up to 500GB, then it is possible to increase limits for individual instances for customers with a silver Google Cloud support package", implying that it's not possible without said silver package.  I imagine you could sign up for Silver, get your storage limits increased, then go back to Bronze next month if you don't need further uses of premium, paid-for support.

Comment: Are you sure you're going over the storage limit? The screenshot shows 274.4 MB out of 250 _GB_.

Comment: ...and I'm glad to say that the language at the above URL has just changed!  It now says "If you require more storage, up to 500GB, contact cloud-sql@google.com"-- no mention any more of silver support being needed -- yay!